# How to exclude one argument from argparser

Tags: python, argparse

Can I define all except one argument for one the option in python?

I want to shutdown all hosts in lab except one host.
For `argparser` I have given `-h ^server1`
which should be pick all hosts from host list except `server1`.

Comment: @ferkulat Thank you for adding this tag where it's relevant but please fix other things in the post when needed, e.g. formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Something simple. Remove any hosts from the list that start with `^`. Call some sort of shutdown function for each host name in the revised list.

```
hostlist = [x for x in hostlist if not x.startswith('^')]
map(shutdownhost, hostlist)
```